# how do you declare an required attribute in XML Schema that references an element?

Tags: xml, xsd

> So I have been working on this XML and XSD files and trying to validate it but getting an error for my cid attribute in my XSD file and another error in my XML that may be related the XSD file on the closing catalog tag.
>
> the error in the XML states "cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'catalog' is not complete. One of '{"":photo, "":name}' is expected."

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!--
   New Perspectives on XML
   Tutorial 3
   Case Problem 1

   Catalog of photos from the Our Lady of Bergen Historical Society
   Author: Joshua Carpentier
   Date:   2/20/19

   Filename:         catalog.xml
   Supporting Files: catalog.xsd
-->

<catalog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalog.xsd"
>

<!-- did you want us to included this attribute not sure xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalog.xsd"-->
   <photo cid="c1748" donatedBy="John Borelli">
      <name metadata="tunis cooper property museum">Tunis R. Cooper property</name>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ 
         This photo was taken by John Borelli's great-grandfather. It is believed to have been taken around 1830.
         David Demarest originally purchased the site of the chair factory in 1663. This site was under the ownership 
         of the Demarest family until 1758.  The property is listed in the National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
      ]]>
      </description>
      <date>circa 1830</date>
      <images>
         <img src="1748a.jpg" />
         <img src="1748b.jpg" />
      </images>
   </photo>

   <photo cid="c1749" donatedBy="John Borelli">
      <name metadata="tunis cooper property museum">Tunis R. Cooper property</name>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ 
         A more recent picture of the property taken by the Borelli family.  The property is listed in the 
         National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
      ]]>
      </description>
      <date>circa 1950</date>
      <images>
         <img src="1749a.jpg" />
      </images>
   </photo>

   <photo cid="c1411" donatedBy="Saint Johns Catholic Church">
      <name metadata="saint johns catholic church">Saint Johns Church</name>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ 
         A more recent picture of the property taken by the Borelli family.  The property is listed in the 
         National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
      ]]>
      </description>      
      <date>1921</date>
   </photo>


   <photo cid="c2003" donatedBy="Linda Choo">
      <name metadata="bergenfield elementary school">Bergenfield School</name>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ 
         The No. 5 Public School, a.k.a. Bergenfield School
      ]]>
      </description>
      <date>circa 1920</date>
      <images>
         <img src="2003a.jpg" />
         <img src="2003b.jpg" />
      </images>
   </photo>

   <photo cid="c2078" donatedBy="Maria Giodelli">
      <name metadata="coopers pond water">Coopers Pond</name>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ 
         A favorite spot where we used to go hang out as kids.  The picture shows my brothers Robert and Michael.
      ]]>
      </description>
      <date>May 4, 1941</date>
      <images>
         <img src="2078a.jpg" />
      </images>
   </photo>

   <photo cid="c2079" donatedBy="Linda Uffington">
      <name metadata="watch timekeeping pocket railway">Pocket Watch</name>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ 
         A more recent picture of the property taken by the Borelli family.  The property is listed in the 
         National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
      ]]>
      </description>
      <date>circa 1870</date>
      <images>
         <img src="2079a.jpg" />
         <img src="2079b.jpg" />
      </images>
   </photo>

   <photo cid="c3233">
      <name metadata="hotel">Bergenfield Hotel</name>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ 
         The Knollfield Hotel was known as the Bergenfield Hotel.  The property is listed in the 
         National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
      ]]>
      </description>
      <date>circa 1920</date>
   </photo>

   <photo cid="c3433">
      <name metadata="sweeney coal fuel">Sweeney Coal</name>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ 
         Sweeney Fuel Company located near New Bridge Road and railroad tracks.
      ]]>
      </description>
      <date>1920</date>
      <images>
         <img src="3433a.jpg" />
         <img src="3433b.jpg" />
         <img src="3433c.jpg" />
      </images>
   </photo>

</catalog>
```

> the error in the XSD states "s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'catalog' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: attribute."
>
> 4. So far I created a simpleType for cidType based on the ID data type and is restricted to the regular expression pattern c\d{4} and created another simpleType srcType, based on the string data type and that is restricted to the regular expression pattern [a-zA-Z0-9]+.jpg
>
> these are the question specifically 6b is the issue im not sure if there is anything else wrong with my code in regards to the other steps.
>
> 6. Declare the photo element containing the following sequence of nested child elements—name,
>      description, date, and images. Set the following properties for the nested elements:
>
> a. All of the child elements should contain string data. The name element should also support the metadata attribute.
>
> b. The cid attribute is required. The donatedBy attribute is optional.
>
> 7. Declare the img element. It has no content and contains a required attribute, src.
> 8. Declare the following attributes and elements:
>
> a. The attribute metadata must have the string data type.
>
> b. The attribute cid must have the cidType data type.
>
> c. The attribute src must have the srcType data type.
>
> d. The attribute donatedBy must have the string data type.
>
> e. The element description must have the string data type.
>
> f. The element date must have the string data type.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
   New Perspectives on XML
   Tutorial 3
   Case Problem 1

   Catalog of photos from the Our Lady of Bergen Historical Society
   Author: Joshua Carpentier
   Date:   2/20/19

   Filename:         catalog.xsd
   Supporting Files: catalog.xml
-->      
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:simpleType name="cidType"> 
<xs:restriction base ="xs:ID"> 
<xs:pattern value= "c\d{4}"/> 
</xs:restriction> 
</xs:simpleType> 

<xs:simpleType name="srcType"> 
<xs:restriction base ="xs:string"> 
<xs:pattern value= "[a-zA-Z0-9]+.jpg"/> 
</xs:restriction> 
</xs:simpleType> 

<xs:element name="catalog">



<xs:complexType> 
 <xs:sequence>
 <xs:element name="photo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
 <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
 <xs:element name="date" type="xs:string"/>
 <xs:element name="images" type="xs:string"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType> 


<xs:attribute name="cid" ref="cidType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="donatedBy" use="optional" type="string"/>
<xs:attribute name="metadata"/>



<xs:element name="img" use="required" src=".jpg"/>
<xs:element name="metadata" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="cid"  type="cidType"/>
<xs:element name="src"  type="srcType"/>
 </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I recommend, to separate this into two questions, which by this also move towards a manageable size. Dropping elements unrelated to your question would also help.

Comment: Your XSD is severely flawed in respect to usage of `ref` and `use` starting in the line defining the attribute `cid`. Try to validate and correct this one first.